# Labels for line series of different lengths

Tags: r, ggplot2

I do have a problem with one of my charts, where there are four data sets, with three of the same length and one dataset that is a month longer; only the longest data set shows the appropriate label at the end of that particular line.

I'm trying to get all four labels related to each line series to shown on the chart, but I can only get the label for the longest series. Please any thoughts and ideas would be greatly appreciated!

I show the code below and the chart output

```
library(GetBCBData)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggrepel)
# set ids
id.series <- c(ICC_sprd_total = 27443,
               ICC_sprd_corps = 27444,
               ICC_sprd_indivs = 27445,
               SELIC = 4189)
first.date = '2013-01-01'

# get series from bcb
df_cred <- gbcbd_get_series(id = id.series,
                            first.date = first.date,
                            last.date = Sys.Date(), 
                            use.memoise = FALSE)
glimpse(df_cred)

p <- ggplot(df_cred, aes(x =ref.date, y = value, colour = series.name)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_label_repel(data = df_cred %>% 
                     slice(which.max(ref.date)),
                   aes(label = value),
                   nudge_x = 0.05,
                   show.legend = FALSE,
                   size = 4.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,NA), expand = c(0,0)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0)

print(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The original code is identifying points whose `ref.date` match the latest `ref.date` in the data; what you want is the latest `ref.date` *within each series*, which you can get by grouping first.

```
...  
geom_label_repel(data = df_cred %>% 
                     group_by(series.name) %>%  # ADD THIS
                     slice(which.max(ref.date)),
...
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jon, fantastic!